# What's the best way of replacing a material in your scene with another one?

Tags: materials, scripting

What's the best way of replacing a material in your scene with another one?

At first I thought I could simply `bpy.data.materials['old_mat_name'] = new_mat`, but that reference is read only so it throws an error.

Do I really have to comb through every object in my scene for material slots named `old_mat_name` and replace them with the new one?

Is there a better way of getting one material to match another exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a *best* way to do it since it depends on your file and workflow but :

```
import bpy

m_source = bpy.data.materials["Material.001"]
m_target = bpy.data.materials["Material.002"]

for obj in (o for o in bpy.data.objects if hasattr(o, "material_slots")):
    for slot in obj.material_slots:
        if slot.material is None:
            continue
        if slot.material.name == m_source.name:
            slot.material = m_target
```

There actually are material operators to copy/paste material settings but they require a handle on an active object with both materials so it might no be very convenient.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.material.html

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was a better way but thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

To change all objects with old material (brown) to new material (blue).

[image]

Go to the Outliner and select *Blender File* view.

[image]

Find the old material under *Materials*, right click it and select *Remap Users*.

[image]

Select the new material from the popup window.

[image]

[image]

Note that the new material does not need to be assigned to an object, it just needs to be present in the blend file.

Comment: You can do this with lots of stuff, including *mesh data* ;)  Very handy when you forget to instance and duplicate instead.