replace disconnected texture with another texture (like illustrator)
as written in the title, I would need to disconnect textures from a scene, to then reconnect other textures named differently, quickly.
(not opening each individual model by hand)
Do you know when you disconnect graphics from illustrator, when you reopen the file it asks you to reconnect them and you can also choose others and named differently?
Lightwave 3d also does the same thing,
can someone help me?
Thank you very much!

File > External Data > Find Missing Files.

You can do this with Python, but if you wanted to get a specific answer, you would need to explain it in more detail. Not everybody who can help you knows Illustrator enough to know what you are talking about, so describing the functionality you are after in detail would be a good idea. It would be helpful if you described an example situation. What textures do you want to replace, how would you like to specify the ones replaced and the new ones?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267971/110840

hello, thanks for the reply. I explain the project as I set it up on lightwave 3d. I use the program for make mockups. Each frame of the animation has one object and all objects are different.

those objects usually all have a custom texture, according to the project I'm going to do.
They all have the same graphics, but with different textures.
For example today I make png renderings with transparency of a graphic, tomorrow I make them with another graphic.
To do this in a fast and easy way, I delete the old textures from the project folder, put the new ones and when I reopen the program, it asks me to replace them. I replace them with the textures that I decide, even if they are called differently.
I hope I was clearer.
